# How did it get from line 1 to line 2 to line 3 (Vector Cross Product)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

[image: Example picture]

How does it get from line 1 to line 2
can someone explain it in verybbasic terms
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second $=$ expands the cross-product; like ordinary multiplication, it's linear in both arguments. The last $=$ uses antisymmetry $u\times v=-v\times u$, including the "diagonal" special case $u=v=a$, giving$$a\times a=-a\times a\implies 2a\times a=0\implies a\times a=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for any vectors $u,v$, we have $u \times v = -v \times u$ and $v \times v = 0$. So,
$$
b \times c - a \times c - b \times a + a \times a =\\
b \times c - -(c \times a)  --(a \times b) + 0 =\\
b \times c + c \times a + a \times b.
$$